# NodeJS batching async.parallel

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, batching

I have

```
async.parallel(tasksGetContentFromGitHub, function(err, res) {
    // all request over, do something
}
```

the problem is that I might have a large number of tasks, and each of them is sending a request to GitHub.

Since I am a nice citizen, I don't want to send 1000+ queries at once at GitHub, therefore I would like to batch those requests 10 at the time, and then execute my inner code.

Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: see `parallelLimit`: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/parallelLimit.js#L5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [async.parallelLimit](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.parallelLimit):

```
async.parallelLimit(tasksGetContentFromGitHub, 10, function(err, res) {
    // all request over, do something
}
```

Hope that it can help!

Comment: I went through the doc, but it seems like I had miss that one. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Nice. It's great to know that! :D